# Upload time of posts posted using php in Wordpress increasing

Tags: php, wordpress

We are uploading custom posts to our wordpress site using the code below. Basically the posts are a folder containing 10-15 image files which are being recursively retrieved from the C:/******/S1/ folder. A post is created using the name of the folder and the contents, being image files are created as attachment types and associated with that particular post. We are using the groups plugin to handle access control.

The problem is when we first started using this code we could upload 100 custom types in 14-15 mins. But the time is consistently increasing and now it takes around 30-35 mins for the same number of posts, the size and number remaining the same. We are not sure how long this time will reach as we continue to upload posts, we intend to create around 30000 posts over a period of a month. Hence the time is a critical factor. We have uploaded around 3000 till now.

We are not sure why this time period is increasing and we need to keep it constant. We have currently hosted this application on a 4 GB RAM, 2.6Ghz 2 core processor system. Currently posts table has around 53000 entries and post_meta has around 70000 entries. Any suggestions/advice are most welcome!!

Thanks in advance!!

```
function upload_service_register_call_func2() {
echo "<form id=\"featured_upload\" method=\"post\" action =\"/wordpress/index.php/upload-sr-status-v2/\" />";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"my_image_upload\" value=\"C:/******/S1/\"  id=\"my_image_upload\" />";
echo"<input id=\"submit_my_image_upload\" name=\"submit_my_image_upload\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\" />";
echo"</form>";
}

function upload_service_register_func2() {
$filename = $_POST[my_image_upload];

$results = array();


$directory1 = $filename;
$handler1 = opendir($directory1);
$uploads_dir=wp_upload_dir();
// open directory and walk through the filenames
while ($file1 = readdir($handler1)) {


if ($file1 != "." && $file1 != "..") {

$directory = $filename."/".$file1;
$handler = opendir($directory);
$myproducts = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'se******rs',
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 's*******o',
            'value' => $file1
        )
    )
) );

$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
if (file_exists($uploaddir['path'] . '/'. 'ST' . '/' . $file1)) {

delete_directory($uploaddir['path'] . '/'. 'ST' . '/' . $file1);
}

if(!empty($myproducts)){
foreach($myproducts as $myproduct)
{
wp_delete_post( $myproduct->ID, true);
}
}
$post["id"] = wp_insert_post( array(
    "post_title" => $file1,
    "post_content" => "",
    "post_type" => "se******rs",
    "post_status" => "publish",
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 's*******o',
            'value' => $file1
        )
 )));
$content="";
$files = array();
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {

if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
array_push($files,$file);

}
}
natsort($files);

$count=0;
foreach($files as $file)
{

$date = date_create();
$timestamp = date_timestamp_get($date);

$foldercreate = wp_mkdir_p($uploaddir['path'] . '/'. 'ST' . '/' . $file1);

$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/'. 'ST' . '/' . $file1. '/' .$timestamp $file;
$contents= file_get_contents($directory."/".$file);
$savefile = fopen($uploadfile, 'w');
fwrite($savefile, $contents);
fclose($savefile);

if($count==0)
{

copy('C:\********************\uploads\STORE\index.html',$uploaddir['path'] . '/'. 'ST' . '/' . $file1 . '/index.html' );
copy('C:\********************\uploads\STORE\.htaccess',$uploaddir['path'] . '/'. 'ST' . '/' . $file1 . '/.htaccess');

}
$count++;

$parent_post_id = $post["id"];

// Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $file ), null );

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
$attachment = array(

'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] .'/'. 'ST'. '/' . $file1. '/' . basename( $uploadfile ),
'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $file ) ),
'post_content'   => '',
'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Insert the attachment.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile, $parent_post_id );



// Make sure that this file is included, as    wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

$image = $wp_upload_dir['url'] .'/'. 'ST'. '/' . $file1. '/'  . basename( $uploadfile );

 $content = $content."<a href = \"".$image."\" rel=\"lightbox[". $post["id"]."]\"><img style=\"width:150px;height:150px\"; class=\"alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-".$attach_id."\" src=\"".$image."\"  /></a>";


}

$content=$content."";
$my_post = array(
  'ID'           => $post["id"],
  'post_content' => $content,

  );
  wp_update_post($my_post);

 $group_id=get_group_id_by_name( $file1 );
 if(!$group_id) $group_id=4;



 add_post_meta($post["id"],"groups-read",$group_id);
 add_post_meta($post["id"],"groups-read","2");
 add_post_meta($post["id"],"s******o",$file1);
 $em***=$file1;
 $sql2="SELECT de**,bi******* FROM b**********8 WHERE em*** = %s";


 $results2=prdt_run_sql($sql2,$em***);

 if($results2)
 {
 foreach($results2 as $data)
 {
 $de**='SR_'.$data->de**;
 $bi******='SR_'.$data->bi*******;
 break;
 }

 $group_id=get_group_id_by_name($de**);
 add_post_meta($post["id"],"groups-read",$group_id);
 $group_id=get_group_id_by_name($bi*****);
 add_post_meta($post["id"],"groups-read",$group_id);

 echo "Uploaded folder ".$file1."  with permissions<br/>";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Uploaded folder ".$file1."  without permissions<br/>";

 }

}
}
echo"Completed Uploading folders <br/>";
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at your database? How's it's memory usage.  That's a lot of data! Assuming its mysql? Have you tried enabling the slow query log?

Comment: We don't have access to the database currently. I will enable the log and keep you posted MisterSmith

Comment: If the db is not easily accessible can you add some debug logging code to the php?  write a timestamp to the html output or better to a textfile before and after each operation to narrow down what is taking the time. Also  could you have missing indexes in the db? E.g. this `SELECT de**,bi******* FROM b**********8 ... `

Comment: @MisterSmith we decided to take a slightly different approach, we are not inserting the attachments as attachment type into the database but only a href and img src tag in the content section of the custom post type. So we are removing the following code from the above function.

Comment: Continuing on the above comment...I mean we have removed the part where we create an attachment type for each image and insert it into the database. This significantly reduces the database entries as each folder contains 12-20 files and the speed of upload has remained constant. However, we are not sure if this method is advisable and has any other implications.